# Expand Collapse grouping rows of asp.net datagrid control using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've a asp.net datagrid control where I'm displaying grouping rows(if there is order no. link available in a row then that is parent and if order no. is not present then that is child row).
I want to display a toggle button next to each Order no. hyperlink and expand collapse each grouping when clicked.
There is pagination also so in some cases grouping data gets displayed to the next page that's why I'm checking for Order# link control presence.
Below is the image that is not working correctly:
[image]

Following is the sample of generated html markup:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="dgFullOrdersView" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="FolderImageSHeader">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="FilingSHeader">FOLDER</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="FilingSHeader">VIEW</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="FilingSHeader">ORDER#</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="FilingSHeader">DEBTOR</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="FilingSHeader">JURISDICTION</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="FilingSHeader">TYPE</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">Bill Code</td>
         <td class="FilingSHeader">REF1</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="FilingSHeader" style="white-space:nowrap;">ORDER DATE</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="FilingSHeader">STATUS</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="FilingSHeader" align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;">ACTION</td>
         <td class="SpacerSColumn">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="UCCFilingPortfolioTableItem">
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>
            <span id="dgFullOrdersView_ctl02_lblSearchref">123-TEST</span>
         </td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>
         </td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>
            <img id="dgFullOrdersView_ctl02_imgRecurring" title="Scheduled Generated Order" style="border-width:0px;">&nbsp;
         </td>
         <td>
            <input name="dgFullOrdersView$ctl02$btnToggle" type="button" id="dgFullOrdersView_ctl02_btnToggle" onclick="ToggleGroup(this);" value=">">&nbsp;
         </td>
         <td>
            <a id="dgFullOrdersView_ctl03_hypOrder" class="mainnav1" 
               onclick="LogOrderViewDetails(237851)" href="OrderResults.aspx?OrderNo=237851">237851</a>
         </td>
         <td>
         </td>
         <td>
            <font class="mainnav2">
            <span id="dgFullOrdersView_ctl02_lblSearchKey">SUBWAY</span></font>
         </td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>
            AL
            :
            Sec.of State
         </td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>
            <span id="dgFullOrdersView_ctl02_lblOrderType"></span>
         </td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>123456789</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>08/15/2023</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>
            <font class="mainnav2">
            <span id="dgFullOrdersView_ctl02_lblStatus">Submitted</span>    
            </font>                              
         </td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td align="left">                                
      </tr>
<--OTHER TRs here-->
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and following is the script that I'm using but it is expanding collapsing incorrectly:

```
function ToggleGroup(button) {
            var row = $(button).closest('tr');
            var group = row.nextUntil('tr:has(button)');
            group.toggle();
        }
```

Kindly suggest how to implement this efficiently.